# ListView items - going Back and Forth

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

Ok, I have a ListView inside a DialogPreference that is populated with an CustomAdapter extending BaseAdapter.

When the dialog comes up the first time, it shows a list of Root directories that I get from a web api. Once the user clicks on one of the ListItems, I now show the sub Directories.

Before adding the new listview I do this to clear the current one:

```
lv.setAdapter(null);
```

I would like to have sort of a breadcrumb where the user can see in what directory he is, and can easily click on one of the crumbs to go back to that directory.

```
Root > Channel > SubChannel > SubSub > Foo
```

Im not sure how this would or should be done. I would just like to go back basically, as a back buttons would have done (although im not using the back button in this case).

Thanks for any suggestions in the right direction.

Comment: If I would implement some thing like that i guess i would use clickable textviews inside of a horizontal scroll view , separated by not clickable ">" for you breadcrumb file path. each text view will be configured to show the appropriate file list for this specific file path.

Answer (score 0):

How are you handling navigation now?  Is there a set number of levels to the hierarchy, with a different activity at each level, or are you performing all navigation within a single activity?

If each level is essentially just a folder indistinguishable from any other, you'll most likely want to override onBackPressed().  If you're at the top level and want to exit the activity, call super.onBackPressed(); otherwise, handle the navigation yourself and don't call the default implementation.

If you have a different activity at each level and want to be able to go back an activity from your breadcrumb bar, you can call finish().  If you need to go back more than one level you will have to communicate to the previous activity that it too needs to call finish().  The best way to communicate between activities is to use startActivityForResult(), setResult(), and onActivityResult().